# SQL extract unique data from two columns in same table

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I have a table friends, which contains the following columns: 
friend_id and friend_of (both are storing unique user ids)
lets say the table friends contains the following data:

```
friend_id   |   friend_of
-------------------------
   123      |     456    
   456      |     789    
   456      |     123
```

So this means that:
user with id=123 have one friend with id=456
user with id=456 have two friends with ids=123 (friend_1) & 789(friend_2)
user with id=789 have one friwnd with id=456

I want to write a query that given a single user id shows every friend that this user has (with their ids).

For example:
if given user with id=123 the output would be users with ids=456
if given user with id=789 the output would be users with ids=456
if given user with id=456 the output would be users with ids=123 and 789

Can you help me with the query I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(select friend_id as all_friends from friends where friend_of=ID) 
uninon
(select friend_of as all_friends from friends where friend_id=ID)
```

I suppose you are interested in the case where an id exists only in one of the columns. Above query would address this. Note that `union` is used here and not `union all` as unique values are required.

Answer (score 0):

select friend_id, friend_of
where friend_id = '456'

just change ID to get desire ouput

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id='456'`, which should get all of the friends of 456.  Then do a join on your "users" table using the foreign key `friend_of`.

EDIT:  I didn't realize friends was a two-way relationship.  In that case, use a UNION first, some of the other responses talk about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `union`

```
Declare @id int = 1;
select f.friendof from 
#YourTableName as f where f.friendId = @id
union
select f.friendId from 
#YourTableName as f where f.friendof = @id
```